# clang: error: unable to execute command: Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: objective-c, xcode

clang: error: unable to execute command: Illegal instruction: 4

clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)

xcode:5.0    os:10.8.5

Why is there this error, about OS version?
How to modify?
Thank you~~

Comment: What version of OSX?  What version of Xcode/clang?  Show the complete error message.